# openFDA - Open APIs to access Import Alerts, Import Refusals, Warning Letters & Inspection details

Tags: openfda

Does openFDA have APIs to access Import Alerts, Import Refusals, Warning Letters &  Inspection details for a Supplier?

Answer (score 0):

As far as openFDA is concerned, the answer would be no.